# Calculating Kurtosis for Groups Containing Fewer Than 4 Observations

Tags: statistics

Based on some preliminary exploration, here are some interesting observations about kurtosis for when you're calculating kurtosis for groups that have fewer than 4 observations. First, here's the relevant R code.

```
One_Observation_Groups <- list(1, 3, -100, 0, 1000)
sapply(One_Observation_Groups, function (x) {
  y <- sum(((x - mean(x)) / sd(x)) ^ 4)
})
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA

Two_Observation_Groups <- list(c(1, 2), c(4, 4), c(10, 100), c(-1, 20), c(-1000, 0))
sapply(Two_Observation_Groups, function (x) {
  y <- sum(((x - mean(x)) / sd(x)) ^ 4)
})
# [1] 0.5 NaN 0.5 0.5 0.5

Three_Observation_Groups <- list(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 4, 9), c(10, 100, 1000), c(-1, 1, 20), c(-1000, 0, 25))
sapply(Three_Observation_Groups, function (x) {
  y <- sum(((x - mean(x)) / sd(x)) ^ 4)
})
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2

Four_Observation_Groups <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(4, 4, 9, 4), c(10, 100, 1000, 10000), c(-1, 1, 20, -1000), c(-1000, 0, 25, 1000))
sapply(Four_Observation_Groups, function (x) {
  y <- sum(((x - mean(x)) / sd(x)) ^ 4)
})
# [1] 3.690000 5.250000 5.195882 5.247908 4.498946
```

It's obvious to me why kurtosis is undefined for one observation - the standard deviation is `0` for groups containing only one observation, and the kurtosis formula requires a division by the standard deviation. This reasoning holds for groups containing more than one observation of the standard deviation is `0` - kurtosis will be undefined or these groups as well.

It's not obvious to me why, as long as the standard deviation is nonzero, kurtosis is always `0.5` for groups consisting of 2 observations and `2` for groups consisting of 3 observations. (For groups containing 4 or more observations, kurtosis is no longer constant.)

Does this pattern appear for other (possibly higher-order) moments as well?